# R split in Group for parallel execution

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have a simple Table:

```
ID|Value
1|10
1|20
1|-5
2|25
3|2
3|15
4|8
5|18
6|33
6|5
6|50
```

Actual I use this code:

```
for (row in 1:nrow(Table)) {
   ID <- Table[row, 1]
   Value <- Table[row, 2]
   if ( oldID == ID) {
      currentValue <- currentValue * ((100 - Value)/100) }
   else {
      addrow <- data.frame(oldID, currentValue)
      PriceRR <- rbind(PriceRR, addrow)
      oldID <- ID
      currentValue <- 100 - Value
      }
   }
```

To allocated a discount for a later DAX Value in Power BI.

But it slow as hell. So I want to parallelize it.

daply might do the work. But I do not know the inner workings of it.

So basically what I need.

Split table in sets by group of ID.

```
Set1 1,10 1,20 1,5
Set2 2,25
Set3 3,2 3,15
.
.
.
```

Apply function to Sets parallel.

```
First call of function in set, initialize currentValue <- 100
```

after

```
currentValue <- currentValue * ((100 - Value)/100)
For Set1.1 90 <- 100 * ((100 - 10)/100)
For Set1.2 72 <- 90 * ((100 - 20)/100)
For Set1.3 68,4 <- 72 * ((100 - 5)/100)
It should return ID=1 Value=68,4
```

I need to know, is it possible to make a variable persistent in memory for the duration of execute a function an set, as long it lives?

Will daply or a other function create a new working thread to apply it on a set?

I am a R beginner and must jump right in the inner working of the R environment. :-)

Sven

Comment: Welcome to SO! :) In R, the most efficient way to program is not necessarily by parallelizing but by vectorizing. Could you put in plain English what your expected output is? It's probably much easier to re-write it as an efficient vectorized operation than an efficient parallel loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with `reduce` from `purrr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
data %>%
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    summarise(Result = reduce(Value, ~ .x * (100 -.y)/100, .init = 100))
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#     ID Result
#* <int>  <dbl>
#1     1   68.4
#2     2   75  
#3     3   83.3
#4     4   92  
#5     5   82
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
6L), Value = c(10L, 20L, 5L, 25L, 2L, 15L, 8L, 18L, 33L, 5L, 
50L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Comment: Very short and elegant code. :-)

Sorry for my late answer. I am currently on short hours at work. Installed R, RStudio & rtools at home to test it. The TeamViewer to work @Power BI.

Works very good in Microsoft Power BI Desktop. My code was running a round 45 minutes. Your code was done in 3-4 minutes.

I changed data to dataset  and replaced column names with the actual from the dataset. And add PriceRR  <- to data %>% ...

Comment: @SvenUngerecht glad to know that the code helped you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach with `dplyr` and `Reduce` from base R:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(Result = Reduce(function(x,y) x * ((100 - y)/ 100),
                            Value, init = 100))
# A tibble: 6 x 2
     ID Result
  <int>  <dbl>
1     1   68.4
2     2   75  
3     3   83.3
4     4   92  
5     5   82  
6     6   31.8
```

`Reduce` is a tricky function mostly because the documentation is terrible. `Reduce` applies a function with two arguments to elements in a vector in succession with the previous value as the first argument and the current value as the second argument. You can set an initial value with `init =`.

I notice in your explaination that your expected output for group 1 is `68.4`. This is only true if the value for row 3 is `5` rather than the `-5` you posted. Since this was the only negative value in your data, I went ahead and changed it to `5`.

**Data**

```
data <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
6L), Value = c(10L, 20L, 5L, 25L, 2L, 15L, 8L, 18L, 33L, 5L, 
50L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your original script is slow for a couple of reason.  First you are looping through every element in your initial table and not taking advantage of the vectorized nature of R.  Second, there is a `rbind` function within the loop. Binding is a slow process, especially as the object size grows.

It looks likes the objective is a cumulative product of the the value column grouped by the ID column.

Here is a base R solution using the split, apply and merge strategy.

```
Table <-structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
6L), Value = c(10L, 20L, -5L, 25L, 2L, 15L, 8L, 18L, 33L, 5L, 
50L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))

#Create column for the ((100 - Value)/100) factor
Table$factor<- ((100 - Table$Value)/100)

#split by ID
dfs<-split(Table, Table$ID)

currentValue<-sapply(dfs, function(x){
  #find the cumulative product of the factor column
  product<-cumprod(x$factor)
  #return the last value fron the cumprod
  return(100*product[length(product)])
})

#create the final answer
PriceRR<-data.frame(oldID=as.integer(names(dfs)), currentValue)
PriceRR

  oldID currentValue
1     1       75.600
2     2       75.000
3     3       83.300
4     4       92.000
5     5       82.000
6     6       31.825
```

This script is using the `cumprod` function which is vectorized, thus very fast.  Also the above script avoids the slow operation of continuing to growing the final dataframe.

Comment: I tried the first solution from akrun and works for me. Thanks for your Input. Maybe I do a litte test in future to see, with works fastest in the environment.

Yes first I wrote -5 than 5. To be telling the truth. Ich was writing my question literally a few minutes before leaving the office for a long weekend. So no second past on input.